# WEB DRIVER SELENIUM 2.0.8

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I need help, I read about in selenium WebDriver wait forever until the website loads but how do I do this ?. I exported my java test but do not understand how to use that option to wait until the page loads or until all the buttons on the page.

Comment: Please @toniedzwiedz i need you help

Comment: I am not sure - do we have English as official language here? Certainly it would help in cases like above...

Comment: After using google translate I still think the question is unclear :)

Comment: Seems more like question about how to properly use a .Wait() in selenium.  I'd say that it's a duplicate of "http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/webdriverwait-or-implicitlywait-or-explictlywait-nothing-works" or "http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/selenium-2-element-click-is-unreliable", but, neither one has been marked as answered either.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can use explicit wait to wait until your specific element of page get visible.

There are 2 types of wait :

1 - Implicit wait

2 - Explicit wait

Examples are given below :

**Implicit wait**

**Syntax** : driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(time period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

**Explicit wait**

**Syntax** :    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yourelementid")));

**Main concept of both wait :**

**Implicit wait** : It tells the web driver to wait for specified time by poll the DOM. Once you declared implicit wait it will be available for the entire life of web driver instance. Default the value will be 0.

**Explicit wait** : It is the custom wait. It will be used if  want the execution to wait for some time until some condition achieved or element visible.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo mucho en donde usar este codigo. Yo tengo el complemento en el browser existe algun comando que permita esperar por tiempo ilimitado hasta que el elemento aparezca?. Soy muy nueva esto muchas gracias

Comment: No there is nothing to do with that browser plugin for your scenario. you will have to install selenium web driver to your pc and will need to write code using programming language like java to achieve that wait goal. How you can configure all that is given here : http://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Thank you so much however i don't how to use after the installation, can you help me please, how to use this for rus test

Comment: For that you will have to install eclipse , JDK , JRE and selenium web driver JARs to your system. Also it need that you must have basic knowledge of java programming , do you have?

Comment: Yes i have, i tried and i installed eclipse, jdk, and i followed all steps but when i tried tu run a simple test said me the class web driver don't found.                     The code is:                                                                 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Webdriver_class
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("http://google.com");
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
       driver.close();
   }
}

Comment: have you added necessary selenium JARs to your program in eclipse?

Comment: yes, i add the js of web driver in eclipse, i followed steps of thie page http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/how-to-run-your-first-selenium-webdriver-script-selenium-webdriver-tutorial/

Comment: You will have to add 1 - selenium-java-2.43.1 , 2 - selenium-java-2.43.1-srcs & 3 - selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0  to your selenium program. You can do it by right click on your project->build path->Add external JARs.

Comment: please help me, i don't know what hace to do. Thank's

Comment: You will have to add 1 - selenium-java-2.43.1 , 2 - selenium-java-2.43.1-srcs & 3 - selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 to your selenium program. You can do it by right click on your project->build path->Add external JARs.

Comment: Woow you are so good, thanks, I didn't have JRE. I installed and added to eclipse and works! thanks now i'm trying run a real test more complicated from selenium ide.

Comment: Thats Great. Let me know if you have any issue in your real scenarios.

Comment: Hi, i have been worke with selenium ide, i exported a real test but when a tried rus this on eclise the error come back said the class web drive don't found

Comment: Please share your selenium web driver code by update your question. Also forget about selenium IDE when you working with selenium web driver.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are talking about pageLoadTimeout
Which sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error. If the timeout is negative, page loads can be indefinite.

Basically page is considered as loaded when this statement (javascript) evaluates as true

```
document.readyState === 'complete'
```

posible results for .readyState function are as follows one of five values, representing the status of the current document:

1. uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
2. loading - Is loading
3. loaded - Has been loaded
4. interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
5. complete - Fully loaded

Implementation AFAIK depends on language, but more generally you can think about page loading as described in official documentation for Java selenium

> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using
>   an HTTP GET operation, and the method will block until the load is
>   complete. This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as
>   a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. Should a meta-redirect
>   "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout
>   is over, since should the underlying page change whilst your test is
>   executing the results of future calls against this interface will be
>   against the freshly loaded page.

Hope that helps in understanding

More info available [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html), [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp) and [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Navigation.html#to%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Hola, yo tengo el complemente de selenium instaladado en el browser existe algun comando que me permita esperar por tiempo ilimitado hasta que la pagina carge, en casos donde hay lentitud en la red. Soy nueva en esto